# Track Azure Service Bus messages in Application Insights | Python

Tags: python, azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

I created Flask application that is tracked in Azure Application Insights, using OpenCensus package (mentioned in official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python). All the features work great (tracking logging, HTTP requests, exceptions, SQLALchemy queries).

What I want to implement further is tracking call to Azure Service Bus. I found documentation for .NET where it seems pretty easy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#tracking-with-azure-application-insights. Unfortunately there is no such documenttion for Python - how should I implement it?

What I am aware is that I need correlation id to track all events as single action. But I'm lost how to append it to message for service bus and then how to force receiver to start span based on this id to make sure that it will be properly tracked.

Any help suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you have so far, but if are you using the `azure-servicebus` Python library, you can have Service Bus be automatically instrumented by installing [`azure-core-tracing-opencensus`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/core/azure-core-tracing-opencensus), or preferably, [`azure-core-tracing-opentelemetry`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/core/azure-core-tracing-opentelemetry) if using OpenTelemetry instead of OpenCensus.

With these plugins enabled, these will automatically produce spans for all send and receive calls as well as for messages. Each "receive" span should contain "[Links](https://opencensus.io/tracing/span/link/)" to the spans that were created when the message was created/sent. The `trace_id`s can be retrieved from these Links.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Service Bus tracing sample using `opentelemetry`, which you can also use with Application Insights:

> pip install opentelemetry-exporter-otlp opentelemetry-sdk azure-core-tracing-opentelemetry azure-core==1.26.3

```py
import os

from azure.core.settings import settings
from azure.core.tracing.ext.opentelemetry_span import OpenTelemetrySpan
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import ConsoleSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import SimpleSpanProcessor

from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage, ServiceBusReceiveMode

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STR"]
QUEUE_NAME = os.environ["SERVICEBUS_QUEUE_NAME"]

exporter = ConsoleSpanExporter()
trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter))

settings.tracing_implementation.set_value(OpenTelemetrySpan)
with tracer.start_as_current_span(name="MyApplication") as span:
    message = ServiceBusMessage('hello')
    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)
    with servicebus_client:
        sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
        with sender:
            sender.send_messages(message)

        receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME, receive_mode=ServiceBusReceiveMode.RECEIVE_AND_DELETE)
        with receiver:
            msgs = receiver.receive_messages()
            for msg in msgs:
                print(msg.application_properties)
                print(f"Received msgs: {msg}")
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python#tabpanel_3_python)'s a link if you want to learn more.

Comment: thanks, but receiver will be placed in other microservice - how to inject into tracer same trace_id that will connect sending and receiving messages into single call in App Insights? I mean I can access it when sending message using `tracer.current_span().context_tracer.trace_id` but I don't know how to force tracer to use it in app that receives messages